# how to draw a simple polygon in D3, but not a chart, no axis and not date-based data

Tags: typescript, d3.js, polyline

https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js has this awesome but dated example:

```
//The data for our line
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                 { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                 { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                         .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                         .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");
```

How do you write that code in version 4 of d3, preferably in typescript?

So this is how it can be written:

```
   export interface XY {
      y: number;
      x: number;
   }

   drawLine(g: d3.Selection<any, any, any, any>) {

      var lineData = [
               { x: 1, y: 5
            }, { x: 200, y: 20
            }, { x: 40, y: 10
            }, { x: 60, y: 40
            }, { x: 80, y: 300
            }, { x: 100, y: 60
            }];

      var lineDude = d3.line<XY>()
            .x((d) => { return (d.x); })
            .y((d) => { return (d.y); });

      //var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
      //      .append("svg")
      //      .attr("width", 200)
      //      .attr("height", 200);

      var lineGraph = g.append("path")
            .attr("d", lineDude(lineData))
            .attr("stroke", function (d, i) {
               console.log('stroke ' + i); // always 0 :-(
               console.dir(d); // undefined :-(
               return 'red';
             })
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill", "none");
      }
```

The only problem now is I was expecting the parameter 'd' passed to the stroke function be an object of type XY - but it is undefined. I was hoping to be able to have some logic around a (more complex) object to determine what color to use for each line segment.

Comment: Here (no Typescript): https://jsfiddle.net/5m8oy5oe/

Comment: That's pretty much how you would write it in TypeScript also (except maybe use `let`/`const` instead of `var`)

Comment: Nice line Gerardo! Apparently it is TypeScript that is the problem. For the d3.line() call is says x and y are not members of d, and that d is an array. Suspect d[0] and d[1] are what it is looking for.

Visual Studio doesn't like the parameter 'lineData' being passed to lineFunction - it says the argument is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number][]'. 

No idea what a '[number,number][]' is supposed to be.